# Google Analytics 'Visits' count sudden jump

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site that I've been closely monitoring with Google Analytics. Each day traffic has been gradually increasing, and the #1 source is "Google/Organic".

I checked my visit total for 6/20 late in the day yesterday (around 10PM) and it was at ~3000. I checked the visit total for 6/20 yesterday again this morning (around 6AM) and the count had suddenly jumped to over 6000. I don't think the site received the 3000 additional visits between 10PM and 12AM.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior? Does GA do some sort of recalc at the end of the day?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics reports are not realtime. Even though you were seeing your reports at 10pm it doesn't mean all hits up to 10pm had been processed at that time.

The more traffic you get the longer it may take to fully process you account's data. In some cases it can take up to 48h to fully process the data. This means that you could be seeing visits increasing from 2 days ago as the data is being fully processed.